# Mat with type of CV_32F to BufferedImage

Tags: java, opencv

Most implementations of the question "How to convert a Mat to BufferedImage / java.fx.scene.image.Image" involve storing the source Mat in a byte array like `mat.get(row, col, sourceByteArray)` and then either arraycopying the sourceByteArray to the image raster's byte array:

```
final byte[] destinationByteArray = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
System.arraycopy(sourceByteArray, 0, destinationByteArray, 0, sourceByteArray.length);
```

or just directly into the bufferedImage's raster data elements:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(cols, rows, type);
bufferedImage.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, cols, rows, sourceByteArray);
```

My issue arises when I have to work with a Mat with a type other than `CvType.CV_8S` or `CvType.CV_8U` (only these can be stored in a byte array, others require short, int, float, double, respectively).

Attempting to cast the `image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()` to a `DataBufferFloat` throws a cannot cast exception, as does trying to use a float array to store the data when passing it to the setDataElements method.

How to solve this?